# terminating variable argument lists with a null pointer

Tags: c++, variadic-functions, nullptr

We have a lot of legacy C++ code with functions that take a variable number of pointer arguments.  In each case, null pointers signal the end of the argument list. In the legacy code, the literal 0 is used for the null pointer.  Because C++ variable argument list functions do not prototype the types of the variable arguments, the terminating argument is passed as an integer 0.  In some 64-bit environments, integers are 32-bit while pointers are 64-bit.  Is there a risk that the called function will see a non-zero pointer (i.e. the low-order 32-bit word is zero but the high-order 32 bits contain garbage)? Changing all 0 arguments to nullptr would presumably be the correct approach.  My question is: is this necessary? i.e. is there a real risk of error if we don't do this?

```
class mytype;  
void foo(mytype*, ...); 

mytype a, b, c;
foo(&a, &b, &c, 0);  //is this ok ?
foo(&a, &b, &c, nullptr); //or must it be so ?
```

Comment: Note: `nullptr` becomes a value of `void*` when passed as an untyped argument, not an `int`. That's different from passing  `0`, which is (and stays) an `int`.

Comment: Would it be a solution to create a variadic function template instead? You could retain the call semantics.

Comment: I'd extend on Kerrek's suggestion in that you could rename the existing function `foo()` to e.g. `foo_impl()` and then create either a template or a bunch of overloads (how many different number of arguments do you need, after all?) that then delegate to `foo_impl()` with the correct parameter types. Inlining this, your code shouldn't even grow in size or become slower.

Comment: Do not assume that a null-pointer has the same bits as an integer zero.  I have used machines where `long i = 0;  assert( reintepret_cast<mytype*&>(i) == nullptr);` would fire.

Comment: I could imagine a template like `template <typename ...Args> void foo(Args... args, std::nullptr_t)`, say, since `0`, `NULL` and `nullptr` all bind equally well to the last argument. You could use that during the migration.

Comment: @KerrekSB: but we can't use that signature [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d87547840d6cd4ce) :( we have to omit `std::nullptr_t` and *discard* it on implementation.

Comment: @Jarod42: Yes, quite, it requires a bit of SFINAE: `template <typename ...Ts> enable_if_t<last_is_null_v<Ts...>, int> foo(Ts ...ts)` ([Demo](http://ideone.com/eMq2zh).)

Answer (score 3):

You have miseducated your users. If every argument is unpacked as `va_arg(ap, mytype*)`, then users should signal the end of the list with `(mytype*)(0)`, not with `0`. Your existing code has always had undefined behaviour. Even `nullptr` isn't appropriate, because it will be passed as `void*` when it is an untyped argument, so again the correct argument is `static_cast<mytype*>(nullptr)`.

If you are asking for a platform-specific sanction for your undefined behaviour, consult your vendor.

Comment: Do you know of any current machines where the representation of void* and mytype* are different?  (I have used machines in the past where they are, but I think even that would have worked).  In other words, while nullptr is technically still wrong, it will almost always work.

Comment: @MartinBonner: I don't want to go on record making assertions about all hardware for all future times. Don't write code with UB :-S

Comment: "Can you think of any way my code with UB can fail?" Well, maybe I can't. But my imagination is pretty limited and I can give you a long list of examples of people who were badly burned by making similar assumptions. Sometimes they were even true when they were made.

Answer (score 0):

A (partial) solution would be to use operator overloading:

```
void saferfoo(mytype* a0, mytype* a1, ..., mytype* an, int zero) {
   foo(a0, a1, ..., an, static_cast<mytype*>(nullptr));
}
```

here the `...` is **not** the ellipsis from the C++ language, but the ellipsis from our human language.

You will have to define the function for each number of arguments that are present in the code, you will also have to recompile the relevant code. Since it's only past/present mis-use of `foo` that is affected you could do this and use a baseball bat to handle future mis-use of `foo`.

Answer (score -4):

In my opinion using 0 is a non-portable solution. Depending on the compiler, it may be either casted to the data type of the array's element, or as int(0).

Thus, personally I would recommend always use NULL in that case.

Comment: The literal `0` has type `int`, and `int` is not promoted any further when passed to the ellipsis. There's nothing ambiguous.

Comment: It does not depend on the compiler (unless it is completely broken), it is necessarily passed as 0.  Furthermore, in C++ NULL must expand to a integral constant of value 0.  Usually this is 0, but it could be (3-15/5).  What it cannot be is anything cast to void*.

Comment: Besides that, I find the code maintainability much better using NULL in this case.
If tomorrow the datatype of the array's elements is changed by someone without respective code adaptation, and it occasionally becomes to some integer data type, you will get a compiler hint using NULL, or a runtime error using 0.

Comment: @MartinBonner I don't think a compiler need to be (completely) broken if a conversion is done. Such conversions do not have any side effects and the only requirement I see is that when using `va_arg` with the correct type the original value has to be extracted. Also in recent C++ standards `NULL` is not required to be an integral constant.

Comment: @dmi If the datatype of the array's elements is changed I'd reccon that all the uses of `foo` need to be updated to actually pass this new type. Unfortunately the standard does **not** require `NULL` to be a pointer type and therefore it's use will not help the solution to become portable.

Comment: @skyking *If* the compiler can tell that the varargs function never attempts to access the zero as an int, then the behaviour of the varargs function is undefined, so it (the compiler) can do whatever it likes (for example by casting the 0 to `mytype*`.  If it can't tell the that varargs function isn't accessing the 0 as an int, it must be accessible as an int.

Comment: Further, you are wrong to say "such conversions do not have any side effects" (in the general case).  I have used machines where the binary representation of a null void* pointer was 48 bits, the first 16 bits were 0xFFF, and the rest were zero.  An int was 16 bits.   I don't think a C++ compiler was ever written for this machine, but it could have been, and is why the standard requires you to cast NULL to the right pointer type when passing to varargs.

Comment: @MartinBonner Yes it must be accessible as an int via `va_arg`. It need not be accessible in any other specific way. This means that the implementation can convert the `int` to another type given that it can be converted back to `int` and get the original value given that the conversion does not have any potentially observable side effects (except possibly via UB of course).

Comment: For example in a platform with 32-bit `int` and 64-bit `long` there's nothing actually prohibiting the platform to convert `int`s to `long` before pushing them to the stack (and then `va_arg` would pop a `long` and convert it to `int` when accessing it as `int`).